# How do you return to the previous fragment when using a NavController?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation-graph

I am using a navigation graph to navigate Fragments on Android. Currently, I can go from one fragment to another and return on a back press.

Now I need to return to the previous Fragment in an OnClickListener imbedded in a FloatingActionButton hosted in an Activity that hosts the Fragment instead of a back press.

Currently, the following code takes me all the way to the beginning fragment:

```
NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(FragmentSelect.this);
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph, bundle);
            navController.popBackStack();
```

I have also tried  `getActivity().onBackPressed();` which also takes me back to the beginning fragment.

How do you return to the previous Fragment? I am trying to follow this guide,
[Pass data to the start destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data), for returning a Bundle to a start destination, but it leaves out how to return to a start destination.

I also thought about creating another action to return to the start destination, but then the back button will return to the wrong Fragment. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: Get rid of the `setGraph()` call. Just call `popBackStack()`.

Comment: Sorry, I left out a detail. I am inside of an OnClickListener imbedded in a FloatingActionButton hosted in an Activity that hosts the Fragment.

Comment: "I am inside of an OnClickListener imbedded in a FloatingActionButton hosted in an Activity that hosts the Fragment" -- your code snippet suggests otherwise. Regardless, you want to pop the back stack of your *existing* nav graph, not create a *new* nav graph and then try popping the back stack of that. So, get rid of the `setGraph()` call and just call `popBackStack()`.

Comment: Doh, that's what I get for copying and pasting. I removed the setGraph call and it now works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all that you want to do is pop the back stack, `setGraph()` is unnecessary. Just call `popBackStack()` on your `NavController`.

Comment: Now the problem is that I don't have a way to pass a Bundle to the start.

Comment: @JohnGlen: Share a viewmodel between the elements that need to communicate.

Comment: That seems more complicated than it needs to be. I am trying to keep things simple for readability.

Comment: You should use the [Navigation API for returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result)